# Avoid twitter asking phone or email verification selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm building a web scraper of twitter using selenium. Everything works ok until Twitter ask for a verification code send to my phone or my email.
How can I avoid twitter doing this?

Comment: Stop using a bot to scrape twitter since it's against their TOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to register your App and get an Api key from twitter to be able to **scrape** their datas : https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps